# Cant Merge RXJava2

Tags: java, observable, rx-java2

Hi I am new to `RXJava`.

I am trying to get `Users` from multiple Observable which contains an arraylist. I want to merge both the data and publish it to Observer.

Here is my snippet.

```
    Observable<Users> baseDataObservable = mService.getUsers(Constants.SITE);

    Items items = new Items();
    items.setName("User Defined...");
    items.setImageURL("http://www.proto.gr/sites/www.proto.gr/files/styles/colorbox/public/images/fruits/cherry.png");
    ArrayList<Items> items1 = new ArrayList<>();
    items1.add(items);

    Users users = new Users();
    users.setItems(items1);
    Observable<Users> usersObservable = Observable.just(users);

    Observable.merge(baseDataObservable, usersObservable)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
```

In above code, 1st observable brings data from API and 2nd one puts user defined data.

But when I use `merge` on observer I have only single data in `ArrayList<Items>` which is set defined data, the data which comes initially from api shows data provided by 2nd observable.

Can someone please help me

Comment: merge will not overwrite any data. Seems like baseDateObservable is either empty or taking longer to return data.

Comment: Yes, baseDateObservable is taking some time to return data, so how can I merge this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to "merge" the array lists you are getting from both the sources, and you need to combine those into a single list, you need to use `zip` operator instead of `merge`. 
The `merge` operator will emit items immediately when any of the observables triggers, where `zip` will collect result from all the input observables and proceed after that.

In your approach, the observer will trigger twice with 2 results. first the user-defined items, 
then the result from API (with a delay since its an API call)

Try like this to get a combined result

```
        Observable.zip(baseDataObservable, usersObservable, new BiFunction<Users, Users, ArrayList<Items>>() {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<Items> apply(Users usersFromApi, Users usersUserDefined) throws Exception {
            ArrayList<Items> itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            itemsArrayList.addAll(usersFromApi.getItems());
            itemsArrayList.addAll(usersUserDefined.getItems());
            return itemsArrayList;
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new DisposableObserver<ArrayList<Items>>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(ArrayList<Items> items) {
                    // here is the combined Arraylist
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Comment: So here it does not merge automatically, we need to merge data set automatically. Is it because my data is not aware of when it will be available?.

Comment: The `merge` operator does not merge the results. It merges two or more observables together and this combined observable will emit whenever any of the merged observables triggers

But `zip` will wait for a complete signal from all the combined observables and proceed to the next level only after all of them are completed,

Comment: have a look into http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html  and http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html